# how to add right click to exit/minimise to chromium

Tags: chromium

I'm trying to find a way to exit kiosk mode or to exit a full screen chromium.  So i'm running a raspberry pi 4 with raspbian and have netflix, disney+ etc working as a link on my desktop.  I add the desktop command to be in kiosk mode but there is no way to exit if you only have a touch screen.  A keyboard gives the ALT+F4 to exit but if it is a touch screen there appears no easy way to come out of the full screen browser.  So for now I've excluded the kiosk mode and hidden all but the top bar that includes the close button (cross in top right).  That's OK, but it would be nice to somehow do this full screen.  Then either by long press and an option to either close tab, exit or show desktop that gets you out of the netflix...running.
My hole setup looks neat, with 5 streaming services on the desktop, they all run full screen lovely, but no way to exit them.
I did look at a mouse gesturing add on for chrome (crxmouse), but that really did not work for chrome, let alone chromium.
I've come here for some inspiration or maybe another way round it, like a long press to exit or something.

Comment: your question is nor really Raspberry Pi specific ... research `linux gestures`

Comment: I have asked this elsewhere, however, it turns out that the latest raspian has somehow broken the right click on touch screens.  So whilst I have managed to get crxmouse working on chromium and I can right click swipe down with a mouse no problem, I cannot get this to work on a touch screen....yet.

Comment: there may be a way to do a tripple click  ... use it to run a python script that pops a dialog box with a button to exit full screen ... the dialog could require an authorizarion password ... the tripple click could be restricted to work only in one specific area of the screen

Comment: Seems triple click on touchscreen puts most streaming services into full screen mode and also takes them out of full screen mode...except prime.  But they all have a min/max button anyway.  Looks like I'm going to have to make the bar across the top bigger so you can hit the 'x' and stick with that.